# MXNet installation fails on python in windows 8.1 with platform.architecture == ('WindowsPE','64bit')

Tags: python-3.x, windows-8.1, mxnet

On python3 the error stack is:

```
>>> import mxnet
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\mxnet\__init__.py", line 24, in 
        from .context import Context, current_context, cpu, gpu, cpu_pinned
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\mxnet\context.py", line 24, in 
        from .base import classproperty, with_metaclass, _MXClassPropertyMetaClass
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\mxnet\base.py", line 214, in 
        _LIB = _load_lib()
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\mxnet\base.py", line 205, in _load_lib
        lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path[0], ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL)
    File "C:\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 344, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Uninstall MXNet:

   ```
   pip uninstall mxnet
   ```

   (or the version you've installed)
2. Download Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145
3. Install again:

   ```
   pip install mxnet
   ```

   (or the version you want)